# Export resultset from MySql as Tab delimited file. Strings with commas in them are getting Quotes around the string, why?

Tags: mysql, excel, export-to-excel

I am doing an export from a MySQL result-set and what I am finding in the .txt file when I open it in Notepad++ is there are fields that looked like this `Top Side Panel w/ Bracket, Left` now look like this `"Top Side Panel w/ Bracket, Left"` with extra quotes.

This is only happening on the fields with a comma in them. So it does not occur on a record with this in the same field for example: `Rear Baffle`

How do you do a correct Tab Delimited export from MySQL Query Browser 1.2.17 where we do not get added data!?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your methodology for export?  Are you using SELECT INTO OUTFILE?  Can you share your query?

Comment: @MikeBrant - Yes, in MySQL Query Browser click on File / Export Resultset / Export As Excel File... That about all there is to it. In the result set the fields are NOT quoted. But when I open the Excel file, any field that had a comma in the string is now quoted.

Comment: I don't know what logic MySQL query browser uses to escape fields.  Perhaps look at using SELECT INTO OUTFILE query to get total control over how the content is output.

Comment: If I export to Excel I get an XML-formatted file, not a tab-delimited file. I only see quoted text when exporting to CSV (and I'd expect that anyway...)

Comment: @MikeBrant Hi Mike - I was just thinking, you have very good advice about using SELECT INTO. I am going to look into that option more - as I have been just getting away with Tab Delimited txt files as a method of getting data from Excel and back into MySql. - JoJo P.S. Make it an answer so I can give you credit! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL's SELECT INTO OUTFILE syntax to give you a native MySQL way to generate CSV or TSV files. This command gives you full control over how you delineate and escape your fields. See the link below for documentation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php). It offers an export tool that exports csv for MS Excel.

Comment: @Semsem - Do you know what phpMyAdmin will do with srings with commas in them??  How do you get a csv export by the way if you have a column(s) with strings; that may contain commas?

Comment: @JoJo Did you download phpMyAdmin and test it. What I, already, know it has an integrated tool that allow you to export table into MS Excel file. Just try it.